# Which form of "potential" is used when modifying a noun phrase containing an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs

In the sentence:

> The young man with the **potential**(**ly**) sticky fingers was in aisle three.

Which form of "potential" is used? Should it be:

> "*potential* sticky fingers" (because *potential* is an adjective modifying the noun phrase "sticky fingers")

or

> "*potential**ly*** sticky fingers" (because "potentially sticky" is an adjective phrase modifying *fingers*).

Comment: The answer is definitely (2.), but I'm too ignorant of syntax to justify that stance.

Comment: If you use the adjective, it modifies the noun; if you use the adverb, it modifies the adjective—so are they potential fingers which are sticky, or fingers which are potentially sticky?

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "potentially sticky fingers" is correct because the concern in the sentence is not that the young man's fingers might become sticky (the inference when using just potential), but rather that they already are and that the related actions are potentially occurring (in this case, I gather, theft). The differences of the terms are clarified [here](http://wikidiff.com/potentially/potential).

Comment: I agree with the conclusion (that potentially is correct) but not with your reason. I would say that the fingers definitely exist but that they have the potential to become sticky if the young man gets the opportunity and/or gives in to the temptation to steal. Thus his pre-existing fingers are potentially sticky.

Comment: I agree with Ben. What is being modified is not the noun "fingers," but the adjective "sticky."